# Python architecture to connect to remote sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rabbitmq, tornado, zeromq

I have a remote sensor, say a Raspberry Pi which measures temperature. 
I want to be able to remotely control this sensor.

Its connected to the internet by some unknown means, this can be through Wifi, ethernet or GSM/3G. This means that I cannot bind a static IP address to the sensor, so hosting a server is not possible (as far as I know). But it can easily make requests to a known server. I will need to make requests to the device, to get data, tell it to turn on/off etc. But also it will need to push information to the server, like logs etc.

What I have been considering thus far is using either the Tornado web server, using a central server to reply to HTTP or websocket requests from the device in order to give the sensor orders and receive data. The advantage of this is that its rather easy to set up, however I feel like I'm shoehorning Tornado into something it wasn't designed to do.

The other possibility is a messaging service like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ - but to me they seem like more effort because they are slightly more low level (I would need to write routers and such) and also feel like overkill.

Any opinions or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Opinion: tornado can easily do what you require. Data can be passed in in the URL or POST-data, and the return can be arbitrary data (e.g., typically json dictionaries).

Comment: Yes I agree with you. but the communication would need to be very bi-directional in order for the server to also give the sensor commands. It seems like Tornado was not designed for true-always on bi-directional piping.

Comment: I would say that all you require for bi-directionality in this case is regular polling of a get-command endpoint.

Comment: Tornado with a long-lived websocket connection seems like a good fit for what you're looking for; there's no problem with keeping a websocket connection open indefinitely.

Comment: "I would need to write routers and such". No, if your raspberry pi connect to a static, known IP it can be very simple. You may be confused because "router" is a socket type in ZeroMQ (which you would likely use). It would be pretty straightforward. With ZeroMQ you can also have strong encryption built-in.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be too difficult with ZeroMQ. Here's what I would do.

Write a tornado HTTP server in cloud combined with two ports for zeroMQ PUB and SUB sockets. Server provides REST endpoints for users. On raspberry pie connect two zeroMQ PUB SUB sockets to the cloud server.

When you receive a request on cloud server send a command on PUB socket. Set a callback on received data over zeroMQ SUB socket. On raspberry pie when you receive data run your sensor code. If there is reply then send it across the PUB channel of raspberry pie. On server the callback will reply to user.

Below are code snippets for server (cloud) and client (raspberry pie) to do that.

On cloud server run.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import tornado
import tornado.web
import zmq
from tornado import httpserver
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream

ioloop.install()
tornado.ioloop = ioloop
import sys


def ping_remote():
    """callback to keep the connection with remote server alive while we wait
    Network routers between raspberry pie and cloud server will close the socket
    if there is no data exchanged for long time.
    """
    pub_inst.send_json_data(msg="Ping", req_id="##")
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()


pending_requests = {}


class ZMQSub(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        # socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5559')
        socket.bind('tcp://*:8081')
        self.stream = ZMQStream(socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.callback)
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

    def shutdown_zmq_sub(self):
        self.stream.close()


class ZMQPub(object):
    def __init__(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        socket.bind('tcp://*:8082')
        self.publish_stream = ZMQStream(socket)

    def send_json_data(self, msg, req_id):
        topic = str(req_id)
        self.publish_stream.send_multipart([topic, msg])

    def shutdown_zmq_sub(self):
        self.publish_stream.close()


def SensorCb(msg):
    # decode message from raspberry pie and the channel ID.
    key, msg = (i for i in msg)
    if not key == "##":
        msg = json.loads(msg)

        if key in pending_requests.keys():
            req_inst = pending_requests[key]
            req_inst.write(msg)
            req_inst.finish()
            del pending_requests[key]
        else:
            print "no such request"
            print pending_requests
    else:
        print "received ping"


class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # get the unique req id
        self.req_id = str(self.application.req_id) + "#"
        self.application.req_id += 1

        # set headers
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT')

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        print self.request
        if self.req_id not in pending_requests.keys():
            pending_requests[self.req_id] = self
        else:
            print "WTF"
        pub_inst.send_json_data(msg=json.dumps({"op": "ServiceCall"}), req_id=self.req_id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pub_inst = ZMQPub()
    sub_inst = ZMQSub(callback=SensorCb)
    application = tornado.web.Application(
        [(r'/get_sensor_data', Handler), (r'/(.*)')])
    application.req_id = 0
    server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application, )
    port = 8080
    server.listen(port)
    print "Sensor server ready on port: ", port
    ping = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(ping_remote, 3000)
    ping.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

On Raspberry Pie, run the following client.

```
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream
import sys

ioloop.install()


def ping_remote():
    """keep pinging the server so that the connection between server and client is not lost"""
    pub_inst.send_json_data(msg="Ping", req_id="##")
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()


pending_requests = {}


class ZMQSub(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8082')  # replace by cloud server's IP address
        self.stream = ZMQStream(socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.callback)
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

    def shutdown_zmq_sub(self):
        self.stream.close()


class ZMQPub(object):
    def __init__(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8081')  # replace by cloud server's IP address
        self.publish_stream = ZMQStream(socket)

    def send_json_data(self, msg, req_id):
        topic = str(req_id)
        self.publish_stream.send_multipart([topic, msg])

    def shutdown_zmq_sub(self):
        self.publish_stream.close()


def SensorCb(msg):
    # decode image and the channel ID.
    key, msg = (i for i in msg)
    if not key == "##":
        print key, msg
        #####
        #  Do your sensor specific work here. And built a reply for remote server.
        #####
        resp = "response from raspi"
        pub_inst.send_json_data(msg=resp, req_id=key)
    else:
        print "received ping"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pub_inst = ZMQPub()
    sub_inst = ZMQSub(callback=SensorCb)
    ioloop.PeriodicCallback(ping_remote, 3000).start()
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```